# If $f:[,0,1] \to R$ is a continuous function such that $\int f(\sqrt[2n+1] x) dx = 0$ for $n=0,1,...$, then show that $f(x)=0 \forall x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[0,1] \to R$ is a continuous function such that $\int_0^1 f\left(\sqrt[2n+1] x\right) dx = 0$ for $n=0,1,...$, then show that $f(x)=0\,  \forall x \in [0,1]$.

I'm not sure where to even begin with this.

Obviously, showing the composition $f \circ g(x)$ = 0 is similar to $\int f(x) dx = 0$ and I can prove that $f\circ g(x)=0$. But I have to show that $f(x)=0$, and I'm stumped.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666862/if-f-is-continuous-on-0-1-and-if-int-limits-01-fx-xn-dx-0-n) is great for expanding the problem for an $n$ outside the parentheses, but it's not doing much for this problem. Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, using $x=t^{n+1}$ gives
$$ \int_0^1f(\sqrt[n+1]{x})dx=(n+1)\int_0^1t^nf(t)dt=0 $$
and hence
$$ \int_0^1t^nf(t)dt=0. $$
Then now you use the result in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: If $f\in C([0,1]),$ then there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n(x^2) \to f(x)$ uniformly as $n\to \infty.$

Proof: The function $f(\sqrt x)\in C([0,1]).$ By Weierstrass, there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n(x) \to f(\sqrt x)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$. It follows easily that $p_n(x^2) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$

Now let's go to the problem at hand. Let $x = u^{2m+1}$ to see

$$\int_0^1 f(u)u^{2m}\, du = 0,\,\, m = 0,1,2,\dots$$

It follows that $\int_0^1 f(u)p(u^2)\, du = 0$ for every polynomial $p.$ But by the lemma, there is a sequence $p_n$ such that $p_n(u^2) \to f(u)$ uniformly. Therefore

$$\int_0^1f(u)^2\, du = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f(u)p_n(u^2)\, du = \lim 0 = 0.$$

That implies $f\equiv 0$ as desired.