# If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and if $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0, (n=0,1,2,...)$, prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ What does it mean?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

I need help understanding the problem (Baby Rudin Chap 7 #20). The proof is correct, but why?

**Problem:**

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and if $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0, (n=0,1,2,...)$, prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$.

**Proof:**

Let $P(x)$ be any polynomial. Then we can write

$P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0$.

Hence, we have, by linearity of the integral, that

$\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)P(x) dx$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) (a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0) dx$

$= a_n \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)x^n dx + ... + a_1 \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x dx + a_o \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^0 dx$

$=0$.

By the Weierstrass Theorem (Theorem 7.26, Pg. 159, Rudin.), we see that there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. By the above, we have that $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)P_n(x) dx = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$.

The rest is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666862/if-f-is-continuous-on-0-1-and-if-int-limits-01-fx-xn-dx-0-n).

**My questions:**

1) When the problem says $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0, (n=0,1,2,...)$. Does it mean $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^0 dx = 0$, and $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^1 dx = 0$, and so on?

2) Why is $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0$ true in first line of proof? Why is it a sum? I thought we should be setting $P(x) = a_nx^n $. Because $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0$, so $P(x) = a_nx^n $.

Comment: Yes that is what it means. Don't understand the second question. $P(x)$ stands for *any* polynomial and any given polynomial can be written on that form for some $n$ and a set of constants $a_k$.

Comment: I just added "Because $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0$, so $P(x) = a_nx^n $.", so I'm expecting $P(x)$ as a single term, not a sum, by the Weierstrass Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, that's exactly what they mean.
2. What we are given is that
   $$
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot 1\,dx = 0 \\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot x\,dx = 0 \\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot x^2\,dx = 0 \\
   \vdots\\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot x^n\,dx = 0
   $$
   (and so on, as mentioned in 1.) We can freely multiply each by a constant, so that we get
   $$
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot a_01\,dx = 0 \\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot a_1x\,dx = 0 \\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot a_2x^2\,dx = 0 \\
   \vdots\\
   \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot a_nx^n\,dx = 0
   $$
   And integrals (with the same bounds and integration variable) can be added together without issues:
   $$
   0 = \int_0^1f(x)\cdot \left(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n\right)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot P(x)\,dx
   $$
   The given answer explains this in reverse order. But regardless of the direction we compose the proof, from the assumption that $\int_0^1 f(x)\cdot x^n\,dx = 0$ for any natural number $n$, we conclude that $\int_0^1f(x)\cdot P(x)\,dx = 0$ for any polynomial $P$.

Comment: What does "there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$" mean? I thought $P_n$ a sum, $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0$, why is it a sequence?

Comment: @user13985 $P_1(x)$ is one polynomial. $P_2(x)$ is another polynomial. $P_3(x)$ is yet another polynomial. Together, $P_1, P_2,P_3$ makes a sequence of polynomials. It is three long. It is a well-known theorem that for any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, there is some (infinitely long) sequence of polynomials that converges to $f$ in a very strict sense (so-called "uniform" convergence). This makes $\int_0^1f(x)\cdot P_n(x)\,dx$ converge to $\int_0^1f(x)\cdot f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: What's the difference between $P(x)$ vs $P_n(x)$? What's $P_n(x)$ written out be?  $P_1=a_1 x + a_0$, $P_2=a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$, and so on? We said earlier $P(x)$ is the sum of all n terms. I can't make the jump from $P(x)$ to $P_n(x)$ Also, I'll use Weierstrass Thm. later

Comment: @user13985 Both $P$ and $P_1$ and $P_2$ and so on are simply names for polynomials. Nothing about the names says anything about the degrees. Nothing about the names says that the coefficients should be related in any way, and in particular there is no reason to assume that the coefficients are the same. However, when we write "the sequence $P_n$", we really mean "the sequence $P_1, P_2, P_3,P_4,$ and so on".

Comment: Two questions: For $P_n$, when I let $n=2$, 1) Does it mean $P_n(x) = a_2 x^2 + a_1x + a_0$? 2) Does it also mean it's the second sequence in all $n \rightarrow \infty$ sequences?

Comment: 1) There are, unfortunately, two $n$'s here. One in the name of the polynomials, and one in the degree of the polynomials. These have **nothing to do with one another**. $P_2$ could be a degree-one-million polynomial if that suited us. 2) If we want the sequence of polynomials to converge to $f$, and $f$ is not itself a polynomial, then yes, the degrees must increase. But it doesn't have to increase by $1$ every time.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes.

2) Since integration is linear, we have $\int_0^1 f(x) p(x) dx = \sum_k p_k \int_0^1 f(x) x^k dx = 0$.